# Sort list where specific character exists within string

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, custom-lists

Here's a hypothetical for you. If you were to have a list of strings, is it possible to rank that list by a given character existing within that string?

Consider this pseudo-code:

```
List<String> bunchOfStrings = new List<String>;
bunchOfStrings.Add("This should not be at the top");
bunchOfStrings.Add("This should not be at the top either");
bunchOfStrings.Add("This should also not be at the top");
bunchOfStrings.Add("This *SHOULD be at the top");
bunchOfStrings.Add("This should not be at the top");
bunchOfStrings.Add("This should be *somewhere close to the top");

buncOfStrings.OrderBy(x => x.Contains("*"));
```

In the above code, I want to re-order the list so that whenever an asterisk (*)  appears within the string, it puts that string at the top of the list.

Any ideas if this is even possible with LINQ or similar?

Comment: Well, you could use `OrderBy` and supply a custom `IComparer<string>` implementation that does the comparison.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you want to prioritise strings based on the position of `*`, you could do

```
bunchOfStrings.OrderByDescending(x => x.IndexOf("*"))
```

Use `OrderByDescending` because for the strings that don't contain `*` they will return `-1`.

---

Actually, looking further into this it's not going to work straight out the box with `IndexOf`. `OrderByDescending` will work by going for the *highest* ranked index, which in your case is going to be `this should be *somewhere close to the top` rather than `this *SHOULD be at the top` because the `*` has a higher index in that string.

So to get it to work you just need to manipulate the rankings a little and use `OrderBy` instead

```
bunchOfStrings.OrderBy(x => {
    var index = x.IndexOf("*");
    return index < 0 ? 9999 : index;
});
```

*Note - `9999` is just some aribtrary value that we can assume `IndexOf` will never exceed*

[See live example](https://ideone.com/Y2lVmk)

Comment: This is better than my about-to-post answer.

Comment: Awesome, that's pretty much what I was after :) Thanks! Just waiting on the SO timer to count down so I can mark the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `Contains` is what you want to use..

`Contains` returns boolean - so you're ordering by true or false. Since true is 1 and 0 is false - you're ordering them backwards from what you want. So you want `OrderByDescending`:

```
bunchOfStrings.OrderByDescending(x => x.Contains("*"))
```

Which sorts 1 -> 0.

[Click here for live example on IDEOne.](http://ideone.com/y1sNT7)

Comment: This only works if the strings which contain `*` are in the correct order though. For example, if `this should be *somewhere near the top` came before `this *SHOULD be at the top` in the list then they wouldn't sort correctly.